# Creating Story Map AND Twitter Map in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis, esri

Is it possible to create a Story Map and Twitter Map in ArcGIS Online (in the same map)?

Would I have to use code to combine them together?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them. 
Here are a couple of links. 
[Embedding apps and websites in Story Maps](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/04/14/embedding-apps-and-websites-in-story-maps/)
[#UCSelfie Twitter Map](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a16d045c7a694f428df533a4fda14836)
(i could list more links to help out, but reputation limits me to only two links.)

Comment: It seems that I can only embed if I am creating a Story Map Series? (My goal is to create a Story Map Tour and I do not see the option of embedding a web page).

Comment: Do you need static or dynamic data from Twitter? If static to show popularity of topic of the tweet, then you can still work it by creating an embedded map for that slide or slides. Dynamic data you might have to do a lot of coding for this step.

Comment: My goal is for individuals to take pictures of various locations and use a particular hashtag in Twitter so that their post/picture/location will be shown on the map.